# mkfs error: /dev/nvme0n1 apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here

Tags: filesystems, raid, storage, software-raid, mkfs

I added a nvme storage device to a Dell 7820 workstation (alias: new-machine).
The storage device was used in another server (alias: old-machine) and it seems like it was configured as RAID.
Anyway I don't need existing contents of the storage, so I tried to format the disk to ext4 fs, so I ran the command mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme0n1 and got the error that says
*apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here*

```
user@new-machine:~$ sudo mkfs -t ext4 /dev/nvme0n1
[sudo] password for user: 
mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/nvme0n1 contains a linux_raid_member file system labelled 'old-machine:1'
Proceed anyway? (y,N) y
/dev/nvme0n1 is apparently in use by the system; will not make a filesystem here!
```

So I tried to remove the RAID signature of the storage, I ran dmraid command but it does

```
user@new-machine:~$ sudo dmraid -r
no raid disks
```

This makes sense because current new-machine has no active RAID, then how can I remove RAID sigature of the storage device? I have no idea. Because I couldn't format it, I couldn't mount the disk to the system.

Current status of the nvme storage that it is detected but not mounted in the system,  (findnmt returns nothing)
and it does not have any partition (such as /dev/nvme0n1p1)

mdstat, mdadm command shows following.

```
user@new-machine:~$ sudo dmraid -r
no raid disks
user@new-machine:~$ sudo cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : inactive nvme0n1[0]
      1171981824 blocks super 1.2
       
unused devices: <none>
user@new-machine:~$ sudo mdadm --query /dev/nvme0n1
/dev/nvme0n1: is not an md array
/dev/nvme0n1: device 0 in 2 device undetected raid0 /dev/md/old-machine:1.  Use mdadm --examine for more detail.
user@new-machine:~$ sudo mdadm --detail /dev/nvme0n1
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1 does not appear to be an md device
user@new-machine:~$ sudo mdadm --examine --scan
ARRAY /dev/md/1  metadata=1.2 UUID=XXX name=old-machine:1
```

I'm not sure why I see 'old-machine:1' or 'old-machine:2' at all.
Could anyone comment on how to resolve this issue?
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

So it worked with the following command.

```
sudo mdadm --stop /dev/md127
```

It is interesting considering the log

```
mdadm: /dev/nvme0n1 does not appear to be an md device this
```

but anyway it works now! Thanks all who commented on the original question!